# Copying large data from result of query in MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a query that returns a large 'ntext' result. I want to copy this over to a plain text editor (Notepad), but only a part gets copied over.

I tried increasing Query Options -> Results -> Text, but the max seems 8192, which is insufficient for me.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008, if that matters.

TIA!
Raj

Comment: Can I ask why you want to access such large amounts of data through SSMS (besides convenience)?

Comment: There are only two rows I am interested in, and I essentially want to retrieve just two SMTP messages stored as text (for verifying something).
It seems to be an overkill to write programs to extract this information

Answer (score 12):

The way I could get the entire data was using the option "Save Results as..." and then select TXT file, and then you can open it with a good editor like notepad++ , and you will have all the data.

Cheers =0)

Comment: This does not work for me. Same output as the .csv export, which is not enough. Still cut off.

Comment: Does not work for me as well. Result is not full in txt file.

Comment: Works nicely, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
--creates file on server
declare @cmd varchar(1000)
select @cmd = 'osql -U -P -S -Q"select * from yourtable" -o"c:\yourtextfile.txt" -w50000'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

or

```
--creates file on server
master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp your_table_or_view out c:\file.bcp -S -U -P -c '
```

or

```
--the limit of 8192 is per column, so split your column into multiple columns
--you will get a 1 character gap between these "columns" though
;WITH YourQuery AS
(
    SELECT
        col1
        FROM ...
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(col1,1,8192), SUBSTRING(col1,8193,8192), SUBSTRING(col1,16385,8192) --...
```

Comment: Thanks for three solutions KM.

By "server" do you mean the file will be created on the DB server? Argh, that makes it almost useless to me (since I can't access the DB server file system)

Comment: @Raj, yes, server is on the database's machine.

Answer (score -2):

Fast and dirty way

1. Right click table - 'Edit first 200 rows'
2. Click 'Show SQL pane'
3. Edit SQL to return required value
4. Click Execute SQL
5. Now you can copy big result

I've just copied 87K text this way.

Comment: Only XML types work like this, the text types are limited to 65536

Comment: +1 for the Edit first 200 rows option it may be limited to 65k but it is definitely better than copying from a select statement, it also keeps your formatting in my case a formatted JSON string.